# How Do I get Packets from Locally hosted website on remote computer with pyshark

Tags: python, scapy, pyshark

I am trying to get packets from a website hosted locally on remote computer(Test purpose) using pyshark.

Here is my code:

```
import pyshark

def print_live_dns():
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture("wlan0")
   for packet in capture:
      # print(packet)
      with open('packets.txt', 'a') as f:
         f.write(str(packet))
      if "DNS" in packet and not packet.dns.flags_response.int_value:
         print(packet.dns.qry_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_live_dns()
```

With this code I only get packets from the internet. which is not what I need. How do I achieve this? using either `pyshark, scapy, nmap`  etc

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please provide excepted output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032032/finding-the-intersection-of-nested-lists-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the intersection of nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032032/finding-the-intersection-of-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use set intersection

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>>
>>> my_list = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,9], [2,4,78,23,13,7], [3,2,5,98,23,1,34]]
>>> list(reduce(lambda x, y: set(x).intersection(set(y)), my_list))
[2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce

my_list = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,9], [2,4,78,23,13,56,7], [3,2,5,98,23,1,34]]

print(reduce(set.intersection, map(set, my_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to generate a `set` from each sub-list and calculate their **intersection** (the set including just elements present in each set):

```
intersect = set(my_list[0]) & set(my_list[1]) & set(my_list[2])
```

Before printing the result we first convert it back to a `list`:

```
print( list(intersect) )
```

My example is tailored on your specific list, intersection operator `&` is used. My next step would have been the explanation of the general case (N sub-lists) with loops, but it has been perfectly covered by the other answers and it would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets

```
my_list = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,9], [2,4,78,23,13,56,7], [3,2,5,98,23,1,34]]
res = set(my_list[0])
for i in range(1, len(my_list)):
    res = res.intersection(set(my_list[i]))
print(list(res))
```

Output

```
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
my_list = [[2,3,5,56,7,8,9], [2,4,78,23,13,56,7], [3,2,5,98,23,1,34]]

# use the first list converted to a set as result, use *rest for iteration
result, *rest = map(set, my_list)
for sub in rest:
    result = result.intersection(sub)

print(result)
```

Another way of doing it is applying the `&` operation to converted sets:

```
import operator
list(reduce(operator.and_, map(set, l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sets for this

```
 my_list = [[2,3,5,6,7,8,9], [2,4,78,23,13,56,7], [3,2,5,98,23,1,34]]
 first_tuple_list = [set(lst) for lst in my_list]
 print(first_tuple_list[0] & first_tuple_list[1] & first_tuple_list[2])
```